# WSO2 1.9 API Manager HTTP Listener - Transports Statistics

Tags: wso2

I'm not receiving any input on the Transport Statistics metrics page on the API Manager web page.  Is this supposed to work out of the box? Please help me with how to setup this up so I receive data. I'm looking to identify how much data (size) is being transferred during API calls.  Is there a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Manager is not provided Transport Statistics by default. We can configure Wso2 API Manger 1.9 with WSO2 BAM (Business Activity Monitor) or Google Analytics to achieve your requirement.
You can follow the steps mentioned in the document [1] to configure API manager with BAM or Google Analytics.

[1]- https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Working+with+Statistics

Comment: Susankha - Thank you for your reply.  I have followed the steps you provided. BAM is configured and is generating metrics for all except Transport Statistics, which has no values (everything zero).  Is there something specific that I need to turn on for those? I saw there is configuration for HTTP Listener in the axis2.xml file. Does anything need to be configured there?  I can't use Google as I am not deployed on a network that has access to the internet.

Comment: Currently You can only get following statics from API manager after configuring with the BAM.
If you follow the steps mentioned in the provided document, you shoul see the following statics.

API Subscriptions,API Usage,API Response Times,API Last Access Times,API Usage by Resource Path,API Usage by Destination,API Usage by User: Number of times a user has accessed an API
Faulty Invocations
But according to the curent architecture, you can't  see "how much data (size) is being transferred during API calls".